# What does the "last then" phrase mean in the given sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the "Last then." phrase in the following sentence?

> **Last then**. Although I’ll concede that some online degree programs
>   aren’t accredited and not worth the time, it’s simply not true that
>   top schools don’t offer online degree programs.

Comment: Can you provide more context? What comes before "Last then."?

Comment: @Mixolydian It argues some reasons: First, ... . Second ... . Last then. Although ...

Comment: Are you asking what "Last then" means or the sentence that comes afterwards?

Comment: *Last then* is not a complete sentence. (Despite that, it might make sense, depending on what comes before it.)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by you in the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203326/what-does-mean-the-last-then-phrase#comment393958_203326), the source of the text in question seems to be arguing in the favor of online degree programs.

Ergo, "Last then" simply refers to the fact that the sentence that follows it is the last point the writer of the text is making.